# Amazon onebox too large

Tags: bug, chat, design, onebox

It seems that the Amazon onebox doesn't truncate text. Pasting a product link with a particularly long description results in a rather large onebox:

[image]

For comparison, a long question from somewhere on SE will have its content truncated, so that the box doesn't get so big:

[image]

(Yes it's a similar question, but I don't believe it's a duplicate. [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158524/make-chat-oneboxing-smaller-and-less-obnoxious-click-to-enlarge-instead))

Can it be made so Amazon oneboxes have a limit set for the description shown, so the box isn't quite so large when the seller has a lot to say?

Comment: @ShadowWizard dupes of non-answered questions are possible here?

Comment: Possible and quite common, as bugs sometimes take long time to be fixed, and people keep noticing and reporting them. Don't feel bad, dupes are totally fine to have.

Comment: @ShadowWizard no, that's not my worry. But It's almost a three year old question, and nothing has come of it. Is it not OK to raise issues again in this way (even though it wasn't deliberate)?

Comment: Nope. Proper way to bump a bug report is editing the original, or starting a bounty. Both put it back on top and SE team gets another chance to take a look.

Comment: I'll do that in the future then. I've never been good at asking questions, only answering them :p